# Reference to this not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code defining a singleton:

```
var S = (function() {
    this._enabled = false;

    this.initialize = function() {
        this._doit();
    };

    this._doit = function() {
        this._enabled = true;
    };

    // Exporting
    return {
        Initialize: this.initialize
    };
})();
```

I call:

```
S.Initialize();
```

And get this:

> 'this._doit' is not a function

If I just call `_doit()` in `initialize` then it is ok... But I thought I did set `this` properly to be used across elements in my class.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're doing here I would avoid `this` completely, e.g.:

```
var S = (function() {
    var _enabled = false;

    function initialize() {
        _doit();
    };

    function _doit() {
        _enabled = true;
    };

    // Exporting
    return {
        Initialize: initialize
    };
})();
```

Because you're not using the `new` keyword, `this` refers to the `window` object (or in strict mode, it would refer to `undefined`). Another option would be to use `new function()`, e.g.:

```
var S = new function() {
    this._enabled = false;

    this.initialize = function() {
        this._doit();
    };

    this._doit = function() {
        this._enabled = true;
    };
};

S.initialize();
```

Comment: Fine, what if I wanted `_doit` to be private?

Comment: In my first example, everything except the 'Initialize' method is private.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are returning an object containing Initialize pointing to the Initialize function of the `this` *at the time of construction*, which will probably be `window`.

You want to do the following:

```
var S = (function() {
  return {
    _enabled  : false,

    Initialize  : function() {
      this._doit();
    },
    _doit  : function() {
      this._enabled = true;
    }
  };
})();

S.Initialize();
```

which is a very, very different thing.

**Edit:** if you wanted to keep `_doit()` truly private, you could instead write:

```
var S = (function() {
  var s = {
    _enabled  : false,

    initialize  : function() {
      _doit();
    },
  };

  var _doit  : function() {
      s._enabled = true;
  };
  return s;
})();
```

`s` becomes the public face of your object and the function's closure its private side.

Comment: What if I wanted to have `_doit` private?

Answer (score 2):

inside

```
this.initialize = function() {
    this._doit();
};
```

`this` refers to `initialize` object, so what you are doing is:
`this.initialize._doit()`, that does not exist.

Try save `this` context to a local variable and use that one.

```
var S = (function() {
    var _this = this;
    this._enabled = false;

    this.initialize = function() {
        _this._doit();
    };

    this._doit = function() {
        _this._enabled = true;
    };

    // Exporting
    return {
        Initialize: this.initialize
    };
})();
```

Comment: Aliasing `this` as `_this` will not help here because `this` refers to `window`. In order for `this` to work correctly, you'd either need to use the `new` keyword or put everything inside an object literal as shown in @Malvolio's answer. Otherwise you're setting global properties on the `window` object!